# How to put this particular constraint on this link table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, schema, constraint

I have the following three tables in MySQL: Store, Groups, StoreGroup. A store can belong to several groups. StoreGroup is the link table that records the groups a store belongs to. The `Groups` table has the following fields:

```
+------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type                             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)                          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(255)                     | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
| category   | enum('Area','Level','Temp')      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| expireDate | datetime                         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+----------------------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The link table `StoreGroup` that records each store's groups has the following fields:

```
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field   | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| storeID | varchar(16) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| groupID | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | 0       |       |
+---------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

However, even though a store can belong to several groups, it has a constraint that it can belong to only one group in one group category. For example, a store with `storeID` ABC can belong to both groups with groupID 1001 and 1002 since 1001 is from `'Area'` category and 1002 is from `'Level'` category. But it cannot be assigned to groupID 1003 because both group 1001 and 1003 are from the same group category `'Area'` as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM Groups;

+------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
| id   | name         | category | expireDate          |
+------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1001 | City A       | Area     | NULL                |
| 1002 | Branch       | Level    | NULL                |
| 1003 | City B       | Area     | NULL                |
+------+--------------+----------+---------------------+
```

So when one wants to insert the record into StoreGroup table, the following is OK:

```
INSERT INTO StoreGroup VALUES('ABC', 1001);
INSERT INTO StoreGroup VALUES('ABC', 1002);
```

But the following should fail because storeID `'ABC'` cannot belong to both groups 1001 and 1003 since 1001 and 1003 both are from category `'Area'`:

```
INSERT INTO StoreGroup VALUES('ABC', 1003);    --This should fail.
```

So how to modify the table of `StoreGroup` or `Groups` to add this constraint so that assigning store to groups with same category will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to add the group category column in the `StoreGroups` table and then add a unique constraint on `(storeId, groupCategory)`. The table definitions would be like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Groups
  ( groupID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
  , groupCategory NOT NULL VARCHAR(30)
  , exprireDate DATE NULL
  , UNIQUE (groupCategory, groupID)       -- this is needed for the FK below
  ) ;

CREATE TABLE StoreGroups
  ( storeID VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL 
  , groupID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  , groupCategory NOT NULL VARCHAR(30)
  , PRIMARY KEY (storeId, groupID)
  , FOREIGN KEY (groupCategory, groupID)
      REFERENCES Groups (groupCategory, groupID)
  , UNIQUE (storeID, groupCategory)              -- your rule enforced
  ) ;
```

The `UNIQUE` constraint enforces that there cannot be 2 `StoreGroups` with the same `storeID` and the same `groupCategory`.

Comment: Thanks. However, the `category` field in `Groups` table is `ENUM` type which takes three possible values: `AREA`, `LEVEL`, `TEMP`. It is not `VARCHAR` type as in your code. So how to impose this constraint on `ENUM` typed `category` field? Is it the same as `VARCHAR` type?

Comment: Just change the 2 columns (in Groups and in StoreGroups) from `varchar(30)` to `enun(...)`. Both columns have to be the same datatype for the FK to be defined. So if you have enum, make the other the same enum as well.

Comment: I don't really like enum by the way. For one, think about how many work you'll have to do if you ever need to add 1 more category. Changing the datatypes of some columns in several tables is not trival at all.

Comment: I did ALTER TABLE by adding all additional constraints and it works. Thanks a lot. However, this solution has added one more column (`groupCategory`) in the link table `StoreGroups`. This adds some redundant information in this table since `groupCategory` is already in the `Groups` table. And I need to add this additional column into `StoreGroups` table based on the existing `Groups` table in order to achieve that. Is this the usual way to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, this is a common solution, if you want to enforce this rule.